# How to parse child attributes in xml file?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have parsing one online xml file.  [check online link Here](http://www.devilwear.co.uk/store/feeds/dwfeed_item_dropship.xml).
Sample xml file of above url Feed is shown below:
**test1.xml**

```
<products>
<item>
<id>1375</id>
<option name="Colour">
<value optionID="128" quantity="2">Navy|+|0.00</value>
<value optionID="128" quantity="1">Red|+|0.00</value>
</option>
</item>
<item>
<id>1375</id>
<option name="Sixer">
<value optionID="128" quantity="2">Medium|+|0.00</value>
<value optionID="128" quantity="1">Large|+|0.00</value>
</option>
</item>
</products>
```

I using simplexml_load_file 
Like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test1.xml');
foreach($xml as $product)
{
 echo $product->id;
}
```

I got Id as a output.
 But my question is that how to got value of colour and size whithin foreach loop.
I'm currently using

```
 foreach ($product->xpath('//option[@name="Colour"]') as $item)
{    
  foreach ($item->children() as $child) 
   {
    echo "color"."<br>";
   }
}
foreach ($product->xpath('//option[@name="Size"]') as $item)
{    
  foreach ($item->children() as $child) 
   {
    echo "Size"."<br>";
   }
}
```

But it will find all the **option name="color" & option name="Size"** of all the Product.
I want to find the option value of particular product with product id as a output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.devilwear.co.uk/store/feeds/dwfeed_item_dropship.xml');


$item='35282';

foreach($xml as $product) {

$id=$product->id;

if($id==$item) {


        $attr = $product->option->attributes();
        if($attr['name']=='Colour') {



            foreach($product->option->children() as $value){

            echo $value;
            }


        }
}





}
```

Similar for size, and other options....

Comment: thanks @nevermind it's work for me..thanks a lot. it's save my times.

Answer (score 0):

Here `$toFind` variable will hold the product's id to be found, Try

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$toFind =  1376;
$items = $xml->xpath('/products/item');
$result = array();
foreach($items as $it){
   if($it->id == $toFind){
     $temp=array();
     $temp['id'] = (string) $it->id;
     $option = $it->option;
     foreach( $option->attributes() as $key=>$val){
         $temp['option_name'] = (string)$val;
         foreach($option->children() as $optChild){
           foreach( $optChild->attributes() as $key1=>$val1){
              $temp['option_value'][(string)$key1] = (string)$val1;
           }
         }
     }
     $result[] = $temp;
   }
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/107441)

Comment: thanKs Nouphal ..i want to got value like:Medium|+|0.00,Large|+|0.00,Navy|+|0.00,Red|+|0.00